# How do I get the day daylight savings changes for a given timezone in Python?

Tags: python, timezone

I want to know the days that daylight savings changes happen so that I can tell whether a certain datetime is soon after a daylight savings change. Bonus for knowing whether the time shifted forwards or backwards.

In the end something like so would suffice:

```
import pytz
import datetime

def days_after_tz_change(dt):
  """returns a timedelta"""

tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
# dst changes on November 5
dt = tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 8))

days_after_tz_change(dt) # timedelta(days=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a working solution.

```
import pytz
import datetime
from bisect import bisect


def days_after_tz_change(dt):
  """returns a timedelta"""
  transitions = dt.tzinfo._utc_transition_times
  utc_time = dt.astimezone(pytz.UTC).replace(tzinfo=None)
  index = bisect(transitions, utc_time) - 1
  return dt - pytz.UTC.localize(transitions[index])

tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
# dst changes on November 5
dt = tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 8))

days_after_tz_change(dt)  # datetime.timedelta(2, 82800)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're looking for `_utc_transition_times`

```
from pytz import timezone
tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
print(tz._utc_transition_times)
```

Will print a list of the datetimes that the change happens.